# Bannerslider-Magento2 gives compilation error

Tags: magento-2.1, plugin

I downloaded the plugin form here : https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2

When i compile  the code using command

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I got following compilation error:

```
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 42.0
MiProxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 46.0 
MiRepositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 46.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  
Class 'Magestore\BannerSlider\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection' not found in /var/xxx/xxx/magento2/app/code/Magestore/Bannerslider/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Grid/Collection.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Long Research their are few Namespace Name are written wrong.

You can check here the answer : https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2/issues/62/

Replace "BannerSlider" with "Bannerslider" for each namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the namespace "BannerSlider" and same in reported error file "Bannerslider".

Typo mistake.

[edited]

your answer arrived before me ;).